# Java - Apache POI - spreadsheet.getLastRowNum() returns (65353) the maximum row number allowed

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have an excel file wherein I'm getting the address of the last used row through java using Apache POI. With that, I'm using the method

```
spreadsheet.getLastRowNum()
```

to get the last used row. On my first excel file, I can sucessfully retrieved the last used row which is 34. But when I proceed on my second task and work with the second file I can retrieve 65353 as the last used row using the above method but I'm only using until line 30 on my second file.

I believe that the problem might be on my file but as per checking on my file my last used row on the second file is 30, rows below than 30 are not used and higher row numbers are not visible unless scrolled.

What can I do to fixed the last used row of my file? Or what method can I use to just only get the last row that I did some changes ignoring blank rows below?

Comment: There might be that much rows in the sheet. If you selects a column, and changes its style, EG setting background color, it will set the individual cells, not a single row...

Comment: Open your file in `Excel`. Select cell `A1` in the sheet. Press [Ctrl]+[End]. Now the cell cursor will be on the cell in last used row and max used column over all rows. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Locate-and-reset-the-last-cell-on-a-worksheet-c9e468a8-0fc3-4f69-8038-b3c1d86e99e9

Comment: Do you can iterate over a list of rows using spreadsheet.rowIterator() and count the rows used and define some rule that you need to break the count?